Intermittent 405 "Method Not Allowed" Error with Next.js API Route
I'm experiencing an issue with an API route in a Next.js application deployed on Vercel. The API route should accept POST requests, but intermittently, I'm getting a 405 "Method Not Allowed" error as if the request was converted to a GET.
Problem Description

The application works correctly on localhost.
It happens only in my search engine dialog. My other api routes work fine.
In production, some requests to the API work fine, while others fail.
In the browser's network tab, I can see the request is sent as POST, but the server responds with a 405 and logs the request as GET.


But when clicking in the failed request:

This print shows up: {"error":"Method Not Allowed","msg":"GET","url":"/api/search/get-initial-results"}
Here is my api route:
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res
      .status(405)
      .json({
        error: "Method Not Allowed",
        msg: req.method,
        url: req.url,
      });
    return;
  }

  const {
    currentTab,
  }: {
    currentTab: "all" | "posts" | "writers" | "tags";
  } = req.body;

  const identifier = "api";
  const result = await ratelimit.limit(identifier);
  res.setHeader("X-RateLimit-Limit", result.limit);
  res.setHeader("X-RateLimit-Remaining", result.remaining);
  if (!result.success) {
    res.status(429).json({
      message: "The request has been rate limited.",
      rateLimitState: result,
    });
    return;
  }

  let results = {};

  switch (currentTab) {
    case "all":
      // Search in users
      const { data: usersData, error: usersError } = await supabase
        .from("user")
        .select("id, name, username")
        .eq("boosted", true)
        .limit(8);

      if (usersError)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: usersError.message });

      // Search in posts
      const { data: postsData, error: postsError } = await supabase
        .from("post")
        .select("id, title, slug")
        .eq("boosted", true)
        .limit(8)
        .eq("published", true);

      if (postsError)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: postsError.message });

      results = {
        users: usersData,
        posts: postsData,
        tags: tags,
      };

      break;

    case "posts":
      const { data: postsDataPosts, error: postsErrorPosts } = await supabase
        .from("post")
        .select("id, title, slug")

        .eq("published", true)
        .limit(8);

      if (postsErrorPosts)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: postsErrorPosts.message });

      results = {
        posts: postsDataPosts,
      };

      break;

    case "writers":
      const { data: usersDataWriters, error: usersErrorWriters } =
        await supabase
          .from("user")
          .select("id, name, username")
          .eq("boosted", true)
          .limit(8);

      if (usersErrorWriters)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: usersErrorWriters.message });

      results = {
        users: usersDataWriters,
      };

      break;

    case "tags":
      results = {
        tags: tags,
      };

      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  res.status(200).json(results);
  res.status(200).json(results);
}

And here is how I call it:
const getInitialResults = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/search/get-initial-results`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        currentTab,
      }),
    });

    const res = await response.json();

    if (res.error) {
      setResults(null);
      setStatus("error");
      return;
    }

    setResults(res);

    setStatus("idle");
  }, [currentTab]);

  const updates = useDebouncedCallback(
    (normalizedText: string) => {
      setStatus("loading");
      if (normalizedText === "") {
        getInitialResults();
      } else {
        getResponse(normalizedText);
      }
    },
    800,
    { leading: false }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      updates(search);
    }
  }, [search, open, currentTab]);



We are experiencing the same issue. Have you figured out what happened?
